# Dynamic array in Java - so we can decide the size of an array according to user's input

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I just wrote this basic program. It takes 5 values from the user and stores all of them in an array and tells the highest number.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] numbers = new int [5];
        int max = numbers[0];
        System.out.println("Enter " + numbers.length + " numbers:");
        for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();

            if (numbers[i] > max) {
                max = numbers[i];
            }

        }

        System.out.println("The highest number is:" +max);

    }

}
```

I'd like to take off the restriction of 5 numbers and allow the user to add as many numbers as he wants. How can I do that?

Appreciate the assistance. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the user knows the number of numbers in advance (before they enter the actual numbers):

1. Ask the user how many numbers they want to enter:

   ```
   System.out.println("How many numbers?");
   int numberOfNumbers = input.nextInt();
   ```
2. Use that as the array size:

   ```
   int[] numbers = new int[numberOfNumbers];
   ```

If the user shouldn't need to know the number of numbers in advance (e.g. if they should be able to type "stop" after the last number) then you should consider using a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

Comment: AWESOME!! Any other solution to this problem? Is it something that arraylist can help me with?

Comment: Huge thanks immibis - I think I can now take it from here. Stay awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList` and keep on adding elements until the user enters a blank line. [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234) is a tutorial on using ArrayList.

Some pseudocode could be:

```
numbers = new list
while true
    line = readLine
    if line == ""
    then
        break
    else
        numbers.add(convertToInteger(line))
    ...
```

The benefit of this approach is that the user does not need to even count how many numbers he/she wants to enter.

Comment: I truly appreciate your input Adrian..I'll go and learn about arraylists. :-)